# Using Json to Create FormDialog

Tags: c#, botframework

I am trying to build user and conversation specific dialogs using json schema and I have the LINQ queries generating the json perfectly. If I save a sample of the json to disk and use it like the annotatedsandwich example where it is read from a file on disk, it works great. The json is unique per user and conversation and instead of writing to disk I want to use it in memory. I do not see how to pass the json string to the BuildJsonForm method or alternately how to get the userID information in the BuildJsonForm method in order to generate the json based on the user and conversation. I know I am missing something that will let me do this but I am not finding it. Any assistance with how this should be done would be appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of doing (using the AnnotatedSandwich code)

```
FormDialog.FromForm(SandwichOrder.BuildJsonForm)
```

You could just build the BuildFormDelegate and pass your parameters:

```
string schema = "your jsonform schema";
BuildFormDelegate<JObject> formDelegate = () => SandwichOrder.BuildJsonForm(schema);

FormDialog.FromForm(formDelegate)
```

Comment: ejadib, thank you very much for the suggestion. I gave it a try but when I run the example I get a ClosureCaptureException: "anonymous method closures that capture the environment are not serializable, consider removing environment capture or using a reflection serialization surrogate: {instance}". Any thoughts on how I avoid this?

Answer (score 0):

Create a custom form builder to which you pass your custom form json schema

```
[Serializable]
public class CustomFormBuilder
{
    public string FormJson { get; set; }

    public CustomFormBuilder(string formJson)
    {
        FormJson = formJson;
    }

    public IForm<JObject> BuildJsonForm()
    {
        var schema = JObject.Parse(FormJson);

        var form = new FormBuilderJson(schema)
            .AddRemainingFields()
            .Build();

        return form;
    }
}
```

Use as follows (where formJson is your user specific form)

```
var formBuilder = new CustomFormBuilder(formJson);

var jsonFormDialog = FormDialog.FromForm(
    formBuilder.BuildJsonForm,
    FormOptions.PromptInStart);
```

This will avoid the ClosureCaptureExcept‌​ion.